# How to create a form render element for a paragraphs field?

Tags: 8, forms, paragraphs

I have the following EntityForm and I want to add a entity_reference_revisions field for the paragraph entity with the allowed bundle type orga_structure.

I searched the web but haven't found a hint to resolve this.

$form['target'] is the element I tried, but it isn't rendered.

```
class AbsenceConfigForm extends EntityForm {

  public function form(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form = parent::form($form, $form_state);

    $absence_config = $this->entity;
    $form['label'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Label'),
      '#maxlength' => 255,
      '#default_value' => $absence_config->label(),
      '#description' => $this->t("Label for the Absence config."),
      '#required' => TRUE,
    ];

    $form['id'] = [
      '#type' => 'machine_name',
      '#default_value' => $absence_config->id(),
      '#machine_name' => [
        'exists' => '\Drupal\ks_absence\Entity\AbsenceConfig::load',
      ],
      '#disabled' => !$absence_config->isNew(),
    ];

    /* You will need additional form elements for your custom properties. */
    
    $form['target'] = [
      '#type' => 'entity_reference_revisions',
      '#handler' => 'default:paragraph',
      '#handler_settings' => [
        'target_type' => [
          'orga_structure',
        ],
      ],
    ];

    // $form['target'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference_revisions')
    //   ->setLabel(t('Skill'))
    //   ->setDescription(t('The ID of the skill'))
    //   ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
    //   ->setSetting('handler', 'default:paragraph')
    //   ->setSetting('handler_settings', ['target_bundles' => ['orga_structure' => 'orga_structure']])
    //   ->setSetting('handler_settings', ['negate' => 0])
    //   ->setTranslatable(TRUE)
    //   ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
    //     'type' => 'entity_reference_autocomplete',
    //     'weight' => 5,
    //     'settings' => [
    //       'match_operator' => 'CONTAINS',
    //       'size' => '60',
    //       'autocomplete_type' => 'tags',
    //       'placeholder' => '',
    //     ],
    //   ])
    //   ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);
    
    return $form;
  }

  public function save(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $absence_config = $this->entity;
    $status = $absence_config->save();

    switch ($status) {
      case SAVED_NEW:
        $this->messenger()->addMessage($this->t('Created the %label Absence config.', [
          '%label' => $absence_config->label(),
        ]));
        break;

      default:
        $this->messenger()->addMessage($this->t('Saved the %label Absence config.', [
          '%label' => $absence_config->label(),
        ]));
    }
    $form_state->setRedirectUrl($absence_config->toUrl('collection'));
  }

}
```

**Update:**
I would like to achieve that the fields specified in the paragraph are rendered in this form.

Comment: Assuming this is a config entity type (so no ERR/paragraph field attached to the entity type itself), you just need a standard `entity_autocomplete` with settings for entity type/bundle

Comment: Hello Clive, I have attached an update to my question. I tried it with a standard entity_autocomplete field, but it does not render the paragraph form. It gives just a search field for the paragraph entities.

Comment: Those widgets are designed to be used with field-able content entity types, they don't work on other forms out of the box. I'm not sure if it would be more complicated because it's ERR, but there's an example of how to work around it here: https://www.webomelette.com/how-render-entity-field-widgets-inside-custom-form-drupal-8

Comment: Use entity_reference_paragraphs not entity_reference_revisions